# Greek lower case letters python

Tags: python, variables, symbols, beta, letter

How can we use Greek lower case letters in python:(or unicode symbols in engineering)

Like this image:

[image]

As I know β and etc... is like other English letters. I though it was a special letter, that I can not write like others, because there isn't in laptop's keywords.

Comment: What do you mean "how"? You just... do. There's nothing special to do; it just works out of the box in Python.

Comment: for example  beta  Unicode is  "\u03B2"  . but in left side of equal(=) does not output like sent image.

Comment: Please show the problem you got when you tried it.  This works just fine for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. If you're expecting the literal variables named `β` and `u03B2` to be the same variable, then that's not how Python works. But `β` is a perfectly fine variable name.

Comment: at all, I do not know ..how to code it.

Comment: thank you for your attention and your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do any more things. just use that chars!

See:

```
C:\>python
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> β=100
>>> print(β)
100
>>>
```

For use special chars, you can search `Character Map` in window and use this tool.
[image: Window Character Map]

Or use any website be like this: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/character-map.php

Just copy and paste char.

Comment: as I know β and etc... is like other English letters. I though it was a special letter, that I can not write like others, because there isn't in laptop's keywords . thank you very much.

Comment: @vahidvhr I updated the answer for use special chars.